# field initializer cannot reference the non-static field

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to understand how global variables work, and how they can be modified. This is my code, but I'm completely confused when some variables are functions and they need to be called. This is the code that I wrote:

```
public class Globals
{
  public Boolean Ready = false;
  public TcpClient Client = new TcpClient(server, port);
  public NetworkStream NwStream = Client.GetStream();
  public StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(NwStream);
  public StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(NwStream);
}

public void Main()
{
  // How do I access to Globals.Writer?

  Writer.WriteLine("Hello World.");
  Writer.Flush();

  // How do I access to Globals.Reader?
  while ((inputLine = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
    ParseData(inputLine);
  }
}

public static void ParseData(string data) {
  if (data.Length > 4)
  {
    if (data.Substring(0, 4) == "TRUE")
    {
      Globals globals = Globals();
      globals.Ready = true;
      // How do I access to Globals.Writer?
      Writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
      Writer.Flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _How do I access to Globals.Writer?_ ==> `globals.Writer`. Use the instance, not the class name.

Comment: It is interesting to know why on the line before the error you use the correct approach to read a property from the globals instance and on the following line you try to read another property without specifying the instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fields in Globals are not static, you need an instance of Globals to access them. Each instance of Globals will have its own set of fields.

```
Globals g = new Globals();
```

Then, you can access the fields of this instance:

```
g.Reader, g.Writer, etc
```

But, you can also use static fields. You can also make Globals a static class if all the members are static:

```
public static class Globals
{
  public static Boolean Ready = false;
  public static TcpClient Client = new TcpClient(server, port);
  public static NetworkStream NwStream = Client.GetStream();
  public static StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(NwStream);
  public static StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(NwStream);
}
```

Then, you can access the fields by supplying the class name:

```
Globals.Reader, Globals.Writer, etc
```

Comment: If class is static, it says that it can't create a new instance. What should I do here? I'm using Globals g = new Globals(); inside Main and another static function.

Comment: If a class is static, then no, you cannot create a new instance. I described 2 options: 1- Create an instance of Globals (g = new Globals();) and use that (g.Ready, etc) OR 2- Make it static and use the class name (Globals.Ready, etc) It depends on what you need. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring that I think you actually wanted `static` in this instance (or possibly a singleton object) you are just missing the `new` on Globals (you are trying to use `Globals` as a function) then you can simply access the properties of a `Global` instance (which is actually a badly-named local variable):

```
      Globals globals = new Globals();
      globals.Ready = true;
      // How do I access to Globals.Writer?
      globals.Writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
      globals.Writer.Flush();
```

The approach you are taking is not creating "global variables". You are just creating an object called `Global` inside your `ParseData` function and using properties of it.

This will not allow you to access the properties from outside of that function.

*Note: *You would typically NOT use those types of objects in a global way*

### Globals not needed here:

A better solution is to create, pass and consume the objects as needed. You do not need "Globals" at all in the example you show:

```
public void Main()
{
  Boolean Ready = false;
  TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
  NetworkStream nwStream = Client.GetStream();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(NwStream);
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(NwStream);

  writer.WriteLine("Hello World.");
  writer.Flush();

  // How do I access to Globals.Reader?
  while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
    ParseData(inputLine, writer);
  }
}

// ParseData is not well named, as it both parses data AND writes it to a stream
// You should name them after what they actually do (e.g. ParseAndStoreTrueData)
public static void ParseData(string data, StreamWriter writer) 
{
  if (data.Length > 4)
  {
    if (data.Substring(0, 4) == "TRUE")
    {
      writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
      writer.Flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution before. Problem is when I want to send a message from another function but the event is not triggered on the Main function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the "globals" inside a separate class at all.

Just put them outside any method and they will be global to the current class, which should be sufficient.

Don't instantiate them until you need them, especially when they need parameters. This way you can use them across several methods for different purposes.

Example:

```
public Boolean _Ready;
public TcpClient _Client;
public NetworkStream _NwStream;
public StreamReader _Reader;
public StreamWriter _Writer;

public void Main()
{
    _Writer = new StreamWriter(_NwStream);
    _Writer.WriteLine("Hello World.");
    _Writer.Flush();

    while ((inputLine = _Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
        ParseData(inputLine);
    }
}

public static void ParseData(string data)
{
    if (data.Length > 4)
    {
        if (data.Substring(0, 4) == "TRUE")
        {
            _Ready = true;
            _Writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
            _Writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This code won't compile, but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: I tried this also. I initialize them on the Main function to connect. But I can't use them outside the Main function because it says that an object reference is required.